# How to load .DSV file from local system into a Snowflake database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load a .dsv file from my local system into a snowflake database but getting errors.
Could some one help me to load this file.

Answer (score 0):

DSV file format is not supported by Snowflake. You should try to convert it to CSV first and if you still have problems, you may add some code to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes you are correct, I opened the DSV file in excel and later converted it into Excel and also csv and tried to upload the converted files but they are also not working. I am either getting error while importing or 0 rows are getting uploaded with the file format I have created. Is there a way that I can attach a file here then I can do it

Comment: You could add a sample screenshot to your question and some explanations how the file and your code (file format, stage, copy into) look like.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the task by using SNOWSQL CLI using Put and Copy into commands
also the file format which I used earlier I have changed it a little bit based on the format of the data in the dsv file